# Dynamic Dependent Select Box using jQuery, Ajax and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

This is for a University project. I'm trying to create two select boxes which are Manufacturer and Model. The selected choice will then affect the query that will be executed to then populate the select box. It don't work.

**HTML**

```
<select name="manufacturername" id="manufacturername" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>Choose...</option>
                            <?php $ret="SELECT * FROM tblmodel INNER JOIN tblmanufacturer ON tblmodel.ManufacturerCode = tblmanufacturer.ManufacturerCode";
                            $query= $dbh -> prepare($ret);
                            //$query->bindParam(':id',$id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                            $query-> execute();
                            $results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                            if($query -> rowCount() > 0)
                            {
                                foreach($results as $result)
                                {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->ManufacturerCode);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result->ManufacturerName);?></option>
                                <?php }} ?>
                        </select>
<select name="modelname" id="modelname" class="form-control">
                            <option selected>Choose...</option>
                        </select>
```

**AJAX**

```
if(isset($_POST["ManufacturerCode"]) && !empty($_POST["ManufacturerCode"])){
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tblmodel INNER JOIN tblmanufacturer ON tblmodel.ManufacturerCode = tblmanufacturer.ManufacturerCode WHERE tblmanufacturer.ManufacturerCode = ".$_POST['ManufacturerCode']);
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;
if($rowCount > 0){
    echo '<option value="">Select Model</option>';
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<option value="'.$row['ModelCode'].'">'.$row['ModelName'].'</option>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<option value="">Model not available</option>';
}
```

}

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#manufacturername').on('change',function(){
        var ManufacturerCode = $(this).val();
        if(ManufacturerCode){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'AJAXdata.php',
                data:'ManufacturerCode='+ManufacturerCode,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#modelname').html(html);
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('#modelname').html('<option value="">Select model first</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please offer the error message.

Comment: don't have error message, but output not display

Comment: What's your problem? When does it fail/not do the expected? You haven't given anything concise as to where the problem lies exactly. If you `alert(html);` in your success in your AJAX function, do you get any error messages, or does everything function fine, query-wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try "method: 'POST'" instead of "type: 'POST'"

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#manufacturername').on('change',function(){
        var ManufacturerCode = $(this).val();
        if(ManufacturerCode){
            $.ajax({
                method:'POST',
                url:'AJAXdata.php',
                data:'ManufacturerCode='+ManufacturerCode,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#modelname').html(html);
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('#modelname').html('<option value="">Select child first</option>');
        }
    });
});
```